# Trying to remove .php file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I just installed mod_rewrite and enabled .htaccess on my ubuntu apache server.
But the url wont change when I edit the .htaccess to remove the .php file extension from files.

Right now my .htaccess file look like this:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /blabla.php
ErrorDocument 401 /blabla.php
ErrorDocument 403 /blabla.php
ErrorDocument 404 /blabla.php
ErrorDocument 500 /blabla.php
```

Not much, just making sure ppl cant view my filetree and added some custom error pages.

But if I enter a page on my site eg href="page.php" everything works, but if I remove the ".php" from the url bar and reload the page as "www.mysite.com/page" without the .php it still works. And I havent done anything in the .htaccess file, is this right?

if I now add the following lines to the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And then visit **href="page.php"** the url still shows up as **"www.mysite.com/page.php"** instead of **"www.mysite.com/page"**

Do I also need to change the href from **href="page.php"** to **href="page"** ? In order to make the .php extension disappear. - Because that works even if I dont edit the .htaccess file in the first place.

And I always make sure to restart apache when I edit the .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance, K

Comment: Also check that `mod_rewrite` is enabled: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: possible duplication of : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4027458/1403159

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have asked many questions here. Let me answer first one:

`www.mysite.com/page` works without any rewrite rule due to `Options MultiViews`. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

If you place this line at top of your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Then `www.mysite.com/page` will issue 404.

Also to automatically remove `.php` from your URLs use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: It works but links gets borken, my url turs up as "www.mysite.com:8080/page" No idea why the ":8080" shows up, could be something caused since I installed varnish?

Comment: Yes at least none of these rules are adding `:8080` anywhere.

Comment: Ok, so if my href looks like href="page.php" i will get redirected to "www.mysite.com:8080/page" and that wont work.. But if my href is href="page" I get redirected to "www.mysite.com/page" and it works. Its just soon as I add .php to the url and reload the page it redirects me to a :8080

Comment: Try to replace your links like this: `href="/page.php"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didnt help me. Same thing again soon as .php is in the link it gets broken. I think it has to do with apache/varnish. Prob Apache listening on the public interface instead on the loopback interface.

Comment: Hmm ok, Is there any reference to `8080` in your Apache config?

Comment: Yeah, What I followed this tutorial on digitalocean.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3

Comment: Open Firebug and then visit `http://domain.com/page.php` and see what redirects you get in `Net` tab.

Answer (score 0):

1. If `page` automatically renders `page.php` you have enabled [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html), most probably specifically `MultiViews` on the `httpd.conf` level.
2. Yes, you have to link to what you want to appear in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RewriteRule (.*)\ $1.php
```